# Formatting Date from Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to format the way I receive a `datetime` column from sql server. I need to receive it in the format of `02/25/2015`. What is the best way to covert the dates to the correct format?

Here is my select:

```
 SELECT a.[firstDate] AS 'First Date', a.[secondDate] AS 'Second Date'

 FROM [firstTable] a
 left join [secondTable] b on b.[code] = a.[code]

 WHERE b.[name] = 'John Doe'
```

Comment: I've seen countless questions on SO about formatting dates from a database and almost every single one should be done in the user interface rather than the database.

Comment: here's the complete sql date convertion: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspxe:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format SQL dates into strings using [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx) so something like this should work:

```
 SELECT convert(varchar(10), a.[firstDate], 101) AS 'First Date',
     convert(varchar(10),a.[secondDate], 101) AS 'Second Date'
 FROM [firstTable] a
 left join [secondTable] b on b.[code] = a.[code]
 WHERE b.[name] = 'John Doe'
```

You may however be better off doing date formatting in the code that is reading the dates from the database.